# Can tasks on PeriodicWorkRequest be prioritised?

Tags: android, kotlin

We utilise a periodic Worker to fetch the location every 15 minutes.
As long as the phone is actively used and internet connection is available, everything goes by the books.

But when the app is in the background for too long and or even worse when it's in the flight-mode, the gaps between the fetches become as long as couple of hours.

I believe this is because the work is batched and it's up to the Android phone to decide when to run it again.

According to the documentation `setExpedited()` can in fact run a job under a higher urgency and prevent it from being batched.

> Marks the WorkRequest as important to the user. In this case,
> WorkManager provides an additional signal to the OS that this work is
> important.

```
val workRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<WappWorker>(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES).addTag(
                TAG
            ).setExpedited(OutOfQuotaPolicy.RUN_AS_NON_EXPEDITED_WORK_REQUEST).build()
```

I have implemented it this way and successfully compiled and ran it.
But it crashes at runtime:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PeriodicWorkRequests cannot be
> expedited

How odd. So this feature seems to be only allowed for OneTimeWorker and not for the PeriodicWorker.

What are my options? Is there any other way to mark my periodic worker jobs with a higher urgency? Thanks